# Bind value to nth object of array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have an `NSView` and an `NSArrayController` and I'd like to bind some values inside that view to an object in the array controller's arrangedObjects array. How would I do this? I thought about creating a property like "currentObject" and bind everything to that. But this seems ugly to me..

(I only have one view for all the objects but the user should be able to click on next and backward.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you really trying to accomplish? Normally a "detail view" is bound to the array controller's *selection*, not an object at a given index. If you'll always be wired to the same object, just use an NSObjectController, set its content object to the desired one and bind your view to *it* instead.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish something similar to iTunes' mini player. Consider a bunch of objects (for example, songs) and a mini player that displays the title of the current song. I think a "detail view" is what I need. So if I'm right I should bind the view's values to selectedObjects of the array controller and select an object in the array controller?

Comment: "selection" != "selectedObjects" ... You'd then need to disallow multiple selection but yes, if you want to reflect the selected item in the array controller, you'd bind through selection, not arrangedObjects.

Comment: I'm still confused. So I call setSelectionIndex: on the array controller to select an item and I bind the view to "selection" of the array controller right?

Comment: If your user isn't selecting things bound to the array controller themselves, then you probably don't even need it (use an NSObjectController), but yes, you can set the array controller's selection manually. You only bind once - each time the selection is changed, your view will reflect it automatically.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for explaining all of this to me. Otherwise I'd have to go with some ugly implementation.

Comment: If you're already doing most of this by code, you'll save yourself a lot of grief skipping Bindings altogether. Just a thought.

Comment: I used to have an NSCollectionView and now I want something iTunes like. The only left-overs are just the array and its custom objects. So bindings it'll be...